# Plot lines where my data is constant

Tags: matlab, plot, lines

I'm working on a fluid mechanics project and I'm not an expert on Matlab plots. I would like you to help me do the following thing (I'm not really sure what plotting function I have to use and how). You don't need to know any fluid mechanics to answer this question but I will explain you a little bit for a better understanding.

I have an array of data, that represents the value of the stream function (psi) of a fluid inside a duct. Every node is a point in the duct. We know that if we draw a line that goes on a specific (constant) value of psi, there is an streamline. I want to plot these streamlines, without using the function `streamline` , just with a normal plot and using my data.

My matrix is:

```
data = ( 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ; 
8.00 8.02 8.04 8.07 8.12 8.20 8.30 8.42 8.53 8.63 8.72 8.80 8.86 8.91 8.96 9.00;
6.00 6.03 6.07 6.12 6.22 6.37 6.59 6.83 7.07 7.28 7.45 7.60 7.72 7.83 7.92 8.00;
4.00 4.03 4.07 4.14 4.26 4.48 4.85 5.26 5.63 5.95 6.21 6.43 6.61 6.75 6.88 7.00;
2.00 2.02 2.05 2.10 2.20 2.44 3.08 3.70 4.23 4.67 5.01 5.29 5.52 5.70 5.86 6.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1.33 2.24 2.93 3.47 3.88 4.21 4.46 4.67 4.84 5.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1.01 1.78 2.38 2.84 3.19 3.46 3.67 3.84 4.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.80 1.43 1.91 2.25 2.51 2.70 2.86 3.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.63 1.10 1.41 1.62 1.77 1.89 2.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.44 0.66 0.79 0.88 0.94 1.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

Where there are zeros is because there is the wall.

What I want to do, is plot the streamlines when: 
psi = 10, psi = 8, psi = 6, psi = 4, psi = 2.

For example, the first streamline (psi=10) would be a straight line that would go horizontally where it has a value of 10. The second would be a little bit curved (because it has to follow everypoint where it  has a value of 8. And so on.

Could you guys help me with the code? I'm a bit messed with plots on Matlab.
Thank you on beforehand.

P.S: To get an idea this is the kind of plot (using my data, should be almost the same)!
http://i58.tinypic.com/a4sosz.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works for you?

The `2:2:10` sets the level wanted to show. If you want to see better the 10 valued level youcan play a bit with the `axis` function

```
subplot(121)
contour(data,2:2:10,'ShowText','on')
subplot(122)
contourf(data,2:2:10,'ShowText','on')
```

[image]

If you want the plot upside down you can do `contour(flipud(data))`

Comment: Wow, yeah I added `data = data(end:-1:1,:); `
to turn it upside down.

However, how did you do to obtain the second plot? I would like that one only but how did you do to fill it with color if the code it's the same?

Comment: @user3780731 oops I had a typo! the function is contourf

Comment: Alright! Thanks so much for the help. The answer was perfect.

Comment: @user3780731 Accept it so future fluidodynamic engineers can know the anser then ;)